# Does becoming a vampire/werewolf change your normal appearance in ESO?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I.e. when you contract the virus, does your character look any different? I saw someone with red eyes and dark circles around them and thought they were a vampire. I don't really want to look like that but I want vampirism. Please advise!

I know that using vampire/WW abilities will morph your character to another form, but I'm talking about the normal, no effects, character appearance.

Comment: Yes, when you become a vampire you acquire the red eyes as you mentioned and become more pale.

Comment: @Bunyip and do you have no choice in the matter? Is it permanent, all the time?

Comment: I think it is permanent, you will have the red eyes and a bit lighter skin, but it lessens when you feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for vampirism:

For vampires: "As a result of the hemophiliac virus, the infected slowly grow paler. Fangs protrude from their gums, allowing for easier feeding for blood. Eye color changes from the spectrum of average hues to red.
When infected, the fur of the Khajiit alters as the skin of a human or elf would. Long-toothed by nature, the incisors of the Khajiit grow exceptionally long, so that they protrude below the lip. However, their pupils become thinner and more blade-like. The scales of Argonians grows greyer as the infection worsens."

For werewolves you don't change appearance unless of course you transform into a werewolf, and if you do you also have to kill to stay that way.

[Vampirism in Skyrim](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_(Skyrim)) (the visual papearance is almost identical)

[More on Lycanthropy](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy)

Comment: hey wait. your links are from skyrim mate. Not ESO. Not the same :|. But it's probably very similar anyway. thakns.

Comment: The links are valid/ok. The appearance change is very similar (just with a bit different looking characters of course). But you'll get the same bloody eyes, veins, etc.

Comment: @khanahk Wow, I'm sorry I must have completely spaced when reading the tag, sorry!

Comment: Update: your appearance changes in stages, getting more and more pale and red-eyed as vampirism stage increases